# How to loop over files in different directories

Tags: r, loops

I want to loop over multiple files and apply a function to them. The problem is that these files are all in different, but similarly named, directories. The pathway pattern is similar, but the number changes according to what family it's up to.

For example, I have code written as this:

```
for(i in 1:numfiles) {
    olddata <- read.table(paste("/home/smith/Family", i, "/Family", i, ".txt", sep="\t"),
                          header=T)      
    # FUNCTION GOES HERE

    write.table(newdata,
                paste("/home/smith/Family", i, "/Family", i, "test.txt",
                      sep = ",", quote=F, row.names=F)
}
```

The problem I have is that the family numbers don't go in numeric order. Some are labeled just with a number (ex: `2`) and others have a letter appended to that number (ex: `1a`)

In each family subdirectory (ie Family i) I want to call in the same file (the file name is exactly the same but with the number (i) changed according to what family it refers to). I want to loop over these particular files. For example... For family 1a the file is here: "/home/smith/Family1a/Family1a.txt" but for family 2 the file is here: "/home/smith/Family2/Family2.txt".

Also, R doesn't like my use of `numfiles`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `paste0("/home/smith/Family",i,"/Family",i,".txt"),sep="\t"` It appears that you are pasting a file-path with a tab-separator. Same for `write.table`.

Comment: You're right.  However, its still having issues with the "for(i in 1:numfiles)" usage... am I using this correctly?

Comment: @user2726449 are *all* the files you want contained within the sub-directories under the *smith* folder and do *only* the files you want take the form `"Family....txt"`?

Comment: All Family subdirectories are under the Smith directory/folder.  In each family subdirectory (ie Family i) I want to call in the same file (the file name is exactly the same but with the number (i) changed according to what family it refers to).  I want to loop over these particular files.  For example... For family 1a the file is here: "/home/smith/Family1a/Family1a.txt" but for family 2 the file is here: "/home/smith/Family2/Family2.txt".

Comment: Do you want to ignore `Family1a/Family2.txt`? Means: Is the filename always the directory name + txt? Or do you want to read all txt files in a subdirectory?

Comment: Actually - that was a typo (meant to be "/home/smith/Family2/Family2.txt").  But the filename always follows a similar directory pattern.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at `?list.files` and `?dir`, e.g.:

```
files <- list.files("/home/smith", pattern="Family[[:alnum:]]+.txt", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)

for (currentFile in files) {
  olddata <- read.table(currentFile, header=TRUE)
  ## some code
  write.table(newdata, file=sub(pattern=".txt$", replacement="test.txt", x=currentFile))
}
```

Or:

```
dirs <- dir("/home/smith", pattern="Family[[:alnum:]]+$")

fileName <- file.path(dirs, paste0(dirs, ".txt"))
testFileName <- file.path(dirs, paste0(dirs, "_test.txt"))

for (i in seq(along=fileName))

  olddata <- read.table(fileName[i], header=TRUE)
  ## some code
  write.table(newdata, file=testFileName[i])
}
```

Comment: +1 And I had this all typed out and ready to go. Too fast! :-)

Comment: Thanks so much - the second solution actually helped me a lot.  Had to change a few things around but it eventually worked.