# Merging different files in different directories [R]

Tags: r, merge

This is a simple question.  I have numerous outputs in different directories and I want to merge them all.  However, there are two concerns that I have which make this a little confusing for me:

1) I want to set up a loop.  From my question here: ([How to loop over files in different directories [R]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751361/how-to-loop-over-files-in-different-directories-r?noredirect=1#comment27639805_18751361)) I have many files under different family IDs.  Now that I have these output files for these different IDs, I want to merge the files together that have the same Family number - e.g. Merge all Family 1 files (1a, 1b, 1c) together, Family 3 files together etc.

So my files are set up like this:

```
/home/smith/Family1a/Family1a.txt
/home/smith/Family1a/Family1b.txt
/home/smith/Family1a/Family1c.txt
/home/smith/Family1a/Family2.txt
/home/smith/Family1a/Family3a.txt
/home/smith/Family1a/Family3b.txt etc
```

And I want to merge all Family 1 files together, Family 3 together and so on.

2) There are a few duplicate column names in each of these files.  All files have the same headings (well most of them do) so I want to keep the first 5 columns from one (not keep merging these) and merge the last three that differ per file. However, with these three columns, as they all labelled the same and I was wondering whether its possible to label them somehow to indicate which family file its come from - that is, add a prefix Family letter after these three column headers before merging.

So my files have the following heading:

```
rs MID DID PID mom dad rec dom
```

The columns "rs" up until "DID" are the same in each family number (the same in all Family 1 files, the same in all Family 3 files etc) but its the "PID", "mom", "dad", "rec" and "dom" columns that differ between all the files listed above)

I haven't even attempted to figure this out.  I have looked at list.files and lapply and scan but I'm getting more confused every time I do this.

I'm not good at R (which is clear from my previous posts) so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks to Codoremifa - I have the following code.  There are no errors but yet no data is files are being generated... I'm sure its an easy thing:

```
library(data.table)

patternstomatch <- paste("Family",1:11,sep = "")

for (i in patternstomatch)
{
filestorbind <-list.files(paste("/home/smith/",patternstomatch))
  if(length(filestorbind) > 1)
  {
    for (j in filestorbind)
    {
       tempfile <- read.table(j)
       if (exists(paste("/home/smith/",patternstomatch,"a/",patternstomatch,"a.txt"))) 
         {
            masterfile <- merge(masterfile, tempfile, by = c(1:9))
         } else {
            masterfile <- tempfile
         }
    }
    write.table(masterfile,paste("/home/smith/",patternstomatch,".txt"),sep="\t",row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F)
  }
}
```

I have a feeling it might have to do with this part:

```
filestorbind <-list.files(paste("/home/smith/",patternstomatch))
```

But not sure.

Edit 2:

This is my full directory paths, including the names of the the particular files I want to merge:

```
/home/smith/Project001/Family1a/Project001_Family1a_vcf_denovo_rec.txt
/home/smith/Project001/Family1b/Project001_Family1b_vcf_denovo_rec.txt
/home/smith/Project001/Family1c/Project001_Family1c_vcf_denovo_rec.txt
/home/smith/Project001/Family2/Project001_Family2_vcf_denovo_rec.txt
/home/smith/Project001/Family3a/Project001_Family3a_vcf_denovo_rec.txt
/home/smith/Project001/Family3b/Project001_Family3b_vcf_denovo_rec.txt
```

As stated above - I would like to merge all the files that have the same Family number - e.g. Merge all Family 1 files (1a, 1b, 1c) together, Family 3 files together etc.

In addition, the first 9 columns in each of the files of each family are the same - but its the last 4 columns that differ.  Given that - I don't want to keep merging these 9 columns but keep these from one and merge the columns that differ per file.

Comment: `paste("/home/smith/",patternstomatch,".txt")`, you will need a `sep = ""` to have the path generated correctly.

Comment: I actually think this is my problem... I've simplified the file path a lot in my example.  The actual file path is more complicated given the fact there are several files (with different names) in these directories, yet I only want to use one particular file in each folder to merge together.  For example: The files I want to use have this similar directory path:  "/home/smith/",patternstomatch,"/", Project001_", patternstomatch,"_vcf_denovo_rec.txt"  I'm sure its because of this that its not able to find the appropriate files to open & merge together.  Am I right to assume this?

Comment: The `list.files()` function has a recursive argument which returns the full path. You could try storing the result of `list.files(recursive = TRUE)` into a variable and then using `grep` on that. The pattern argument in list.files works only on the file name and not on the full path for some reason. Does that help?

Comment: I'm probably over thinking this... but will this change the loop below it where it is trying to find if a certain file exist before merging? I'm confusing myself greatly here but can't help but think this might not work with the if(length(filestorbind) >1) part?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your directories and files and explain what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Updated original text

Comment: Made changes to my answer, try running it step by step and seeing what values are being assigned to the variables. You might want to be careful with the grep, grep for "family1" would return family10, family11, etc. Have a look at how grep works.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick of reading all same family name files and merging them into one -

```
library(data.table)
patternstomatch <- paste("family",1:10,sep = "")

for (i in patternstomatch)
{
  filestorbind <- list.files(pattern = i)
  if( length(filestorbind ) > 1)
  {
    for (j in filestorbind )
    {
       #tempfile <- read.table(j)
       #if ( exists(masterfile) ) 
         {
            #masterfile <- merge(masterfile, tempfile, by = c())
         } else {
            #masterfile <- tempfile
         }
    }
    #write.table(masterfile)
  }
}
```

patternstomatch will contain "family1", "family2", etc. The loop on i will look for each of these strings in the filenames. If multiple files are found matching a pattern then the loop on j will read them one by one, and keep merging them to masterfile them and write it out as another table.

I don't clearly understand your merging logic which is why I've left the loop on j commented, but I think you should be able to figure it out.

EDIT after OP's edits -

```
library(data.table)

setwd('/home/smith/Project001')
patternstomatch <- paste("family",1:9,sep = "")

for (i in patternstomatch)
{
  allfiles <- list.files(recursive = TRUE)
  filestorbind <- grep(x = allfiles, pattern = i, value = TRUE)

  if( length(filestorbind ) > 1)
  {
    for (j in filestorbind )
    {
       #tempfile <- read.table(j)
       #if ( exists(masterfile) ) 
         {
            #masterfile <- merge(masterfile, tempfile, by = c())
         } else {
            #masterfile <- tempfile
         }
    }
    #write.table(masterfile)
  }
}
```

Comment: I've had a follow up question (see original post)... This is probably me trying to make this more complicated and and missed a fundamental thing.

Comment: Thanks for this... I guess the only problem I'm having now is that the `masterfile` seems to get overidden by the original called in masterfile if `length(filestrbind)` is greater than 2.   Should this be happening?  If not, it might be something I've done in my code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you should try and debug your code yourself. The intent of people answering questions is to provide help of a general nature, and not write code for others. I think I've provided more than enough guidance for you to be able to figure out what the solution might look like and what you need to do.

Comment: True... but I'm not asking you to write my code... just asking whether I've interpreted what you've given is accurate.  If it is, then I need to change your code to fit what I want.  If it isn't, then there is something I've done which I need to change. Because trying to assume what you have given does a certain thing and it doesn't actually do it - gets a little crazy (especially to a newbie in R and debugging). Just asking for some pointers so I can understand this enough to work it out myself.