# Looping through .dat files in R and extracting only specific data as columns

Tags: python, r, loops, extract

I have 900+ folders in my local drive and each folder has a single .dat extension file. I want to loop through each folder to access the file in it to fetch only specific data and write that data in a new file. Each .dat file looks something like this -

```
Authors:
#    Pallavi Subhraveti
#    Quang Ong
#    Tim Holland
#    Anamika Kothari
#    Ingrid Keseler 
#    Ron Caspi
#    Peter D Karp

# Please see the license agreement regarding the use of and distribution of 
this file.
# The format of this file is defined at http://bioinformatics.ai.sri.com
# Version: 21.5
# File Name: compounds.dat
# Date and time generated: October 24, 2017, 14:52:45

# Attributes:
#    UNIQUE-ID
#    TYPES
#    COMMON-NAME
#    ABBREV-NAME
#    ACCESSION-1
#    ANTICODON
#    ATOM-CHARGES
#    ATOM-ISOTOPES
#    CATALYZES
#    CFG-ICON-COLOR
#    CHEMICAL-FORMULA
#    CITATIONS
#    CODONS
#    COFACTORS-OF
#    MOLECULAR-WEIGHT
#    MONOISOTOPIC-MW

[Data Chunk 1]
UNIQUE-ID - CPD0-1108
TYPES - D-Ribofuranose
COMMON-NAME - &beta;-D-ribofuranose
ATOM-CHARGES - (9 -1)
ATOM-CHARGES - (6 1)
CHEMICAL-FORMULA - (C 5)
CHEMICAL-FORMULA - (H 14)
CHEMICAL-FORMULA - (N 1)
CHEMICAL-FORMULA - (O 6)
CHEMICAL-FORMULA - (P 1)
CREDITS - SRI
CREDITS - kaipa
DBLINKS - (CHEBI "10647" NIL |kothari| 3594051403 NIL NIL)
DBLINKS - (BIGG "37147" NIL |kothari| 3584718837 NIL NIL)
DBLINKS - (PUBCHEM "25200464" NIL |taltman| 3466375284 NIL NIL)
DBLINKS - (LIGAND-CPD "C01233" NIL |keseler| 3342798255 NIL NIL)
INCHI - InChI=1S/C5H14NO6P/c6-1-2-11-13(9,10)12-4-5(8)3-7/h5,7-8H,1-4,6H2,(H,9,10)
MOLECULAR-WEIGHT - 215.142    
MONOISOTOPIC-MW - 216.0636987293    
NON-STANDARD-INCHI - InChI=1S/C5H14NO6P/c6-1-2-11-13(9,10)12-4-5(8)3-7/h5,7-8H,1-4,6H2,(H,9,10)
SMILES - C(OP([O-])(OCC(CO)O)=O)C[N+]
SYNONYMS - sn-Glycero-3-phosphoethanolamine
SYNONYMS - 1-glycerophosphorylethanolamine\
[Data Chunk 2]
//
UNIQUE-ID - URIDINE
TYPES - Pyrimidine
....
....
```

Each file has approximately 18000 lines in it (looking at the data in Notepad++). Now I want to create a new file and copy only specific columns from the data. I want only these columns to be copied in my newly created file and the file should look like this -

```
UNIQUE-ID       TYPES        COMMON-NAME           CHEMICAL-FORMULA  BIGG ID    CHEMSPIDER ID    CAS ID    CHEBI ID    PUBCHEM ID    MOLECULAR-WEIGHT MONOISOTOPIC-MW

CPD0-1108    D-Ribofuranose  &beta;-D-ribofuranose   C5H14N1O6P1      37147       NA                NA      10647       25200464        215.142       216.0636987293

URIDINE      Pyrimidine       ...
```

Every chunk of data in each file doesn't necessarily have information for all the columns I need which is why I have mentioned NA for those columns in the output table I want. Although it's completely fine if I get blank values in those columns as I can deal with those blanks later on separately.

This is the directory that has the data -

```
File 1] -> C:\Users\robbie\Desktop\Organism_Data\aact1035194-hmpcyc\compounds.dat
File 2] -> C:\Users\robbie\Desktop\Organism_Data\aaph679198-hmpcyc\compounds.dat
File 3] -> C:\Users\robbie\Desktop\Organism_Data\yreg1002368-hmpcyc\compounds.dat
File 4] -> C:\Users\robbie\Desktop\Organism_Data\tden699187-hmpcyc\compounds.dat
...
...
```

I was really inclined towards using the `dir` function in R referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751361/how-to-loop-over-files-in-different-directories) post but I got confused what to put in the pattern parameter of the function while writing the code as the organism names(folder names) are pretty weird and not consistent.

Any help for getting the required output is greatly appreciated. I was thinking of ways to do this in R but I am also open to try this in python as well if I get good suggestions and ways to deal with this in python. Thanks much in advance for any help!

EDIT: 
Link to Data - [Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LgzHCdAXHQvu5MxVgrk45u5Dfgvxr9-y)

Comment: You don't need to define a pattern, just set the `recursive` parameter `TRUE`, e.g. `dir("C:/Users/robbie/Desktop/Organism_Data/", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach, i this case it's only reading the file you provided but it can read multiple files.

I add some intermediate results to show what the code is actually doing...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

# create a data.frame with the desired files
filenames <- list.files( path = getwd(), pattern = "*.dat$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE ) 

# > filenames
#[1] "C:/Users/********/Documents/Git/udls2/test.dat"

#read in the files, using data.table's fread.. here I grep lines starting with UNIQUE-ID or TYPES. create your desired regex-pattern
pattern <- "^UNIQUE-ID|^TYPES"
content.list <- lapply( filenames, function(x) fread( x, sep = "\n", header = FALSE )[grepl( pattern, V1 )] )

# > content.list
# [[1]]
#                        V1
# 1:  UNIQUE-ID - CPD0-1108
# 2: TYPES - D-Ribofuranose
# 3:    UNIQUE-ID - URIDINE
# 4:     TYPES - Pyrimidine

#add all content to a single data.table
dt <- rbindlist( content.list )

# > dt
#                        V1
# 1:  UNIQUE-ID - CPD0-1108
# 2: TYPES - D-Ribofuranose
# 3:    UNIQUE-ID - URIDINE
# 4:     TYPES - Pyrimidine

#split the text in a variable-name and it's content
dt <- dt %>% separate( V1, into = c("var", "content"), sep = " - ")

# > dt
#          var        content
# 1: UNIQUE-ID      CPD0-1108
# 2:     TYPES D-Ribofuranose
# 3: UNIQUE-ID        URIDINE
# 4:     TYPES     Pyrimidine

#add an increasing id for every UNIQUE-ID
dt[var == "UNIQUE-ID", id := seq.int( 1: nrow( dt[var=="UNIQUE-ID", ]))]

# > dt
#          var        content id
# 1: UNIQUE-ID      CPD0-1108  1
# 2:     TYPES D-Ribofuranose NA
# 3: UNIQUE-ID        URIDINE  2
# 4:     TYPES     Pyrimidine NA

#fill down id vor all variables found
dt[, id := na.locf( dt$id )]

# > dt
#          var        content id
# 1: UNIQUE-ID      CPD0-1108  1
# 2:     TYPES D-Ribofuranose  1
# 3: UNIQUE-ID        URIDINE  2
# 4:     TYPES     Pyrimidine  2

#cast
dcast(dt, id ~ var, value.var = "content")

#    id          TYPES UNIQUE-ID
# 1:  1 D-Ribofuranose CPD0-1108
# 2:  2     Pyrimidine   URIDINE
```

Comment: Use of `require`: https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/ and http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path

Comment: @r2evans learning a bit more every day.. I'll adjust my answer

Answer (score 1):

### One File

Break it up into a few logical actions:

```
text2chunks <- function(txt) {
  chunks <- split(txt, cumsum(grepl("^\\[Data Chunk.*\\]$", txt)))
  Filter(function(a) grepl("^\\[Data Chunk.*\\]$", a[1]), chunks)
}
chunk2dataframe <- function(vec, hdrs = NULL, sep = " - ") {
  s <- stringi::stri_split(vec, fixed=sep, n=2L)
  s <- Filter(function(a) length(a) == 2L, s)
  df <- as.data.frame(setNames(lapply(s, `[[`, 2), sapply(s, `[[`, 1)),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  if (! is.null(hdrs)) df <- df[ names(df) %in% make.names(hdrs) ]
  df
}
```

`hdrs` is an optional vector of column names that you want to keep; if not provided (or `NULL`), then all key/value pairs are returned as columns.

```
hdrs <- c("UNIQUE-ID", "TYPES", "COMMON-NAME")
```

Using the data (below), I have `lines` which is a `character` vector from a single file:

```
head(lines)
# [1] "Authors:"                                                                              
# [2] "#    Pallavi Subhraveti"                                                               
# [3] "#    Quang Ong"                                                                        
# [4] "# Please see the license agreement regarding the use of and distribution of this file."
# [5] "# The format of this file is defined at http://bioinformatics.ai.sri.com"              
# [6] "# Version: 21.5"                                                                       
str(text2chunks(lines))
# List of 2
#  $ 1: chr [1:5] "[Data Chunk 1]" "UNIQUE-ID - CPD0-1108" "TYPES - D-Ribofuranose" "COMMON-NAME - &beta;-D-ribofuranose" ...
#  $ 2: chr [1:6] "[Data Chunk 2]" "// something out of place here?" "UNIQUE-ID - URIDINE" "TYPES - Pyrimidine" ...
str(lapply(text2chunks(lines), chunk2dataframe, hdrs=hdrs))
# List of 2
#  $ 1:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ UNIQUE.ID  : chr "CPD0-1108"
#   ..$ TYPES      : chr "D-Ribofuranose"
#   ..$ COMMON.NAME: chr "&beta;-D-ribofuranose"
#  $ 2:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ UNIQUE.ID  : chr "URIDINE"
#   ..$ TYPES      : chr "Pyrimidine"
#   ..$ COMMON.NAME: chr "&beta;-D-ribofuranose or something"
```

And the final product:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(text2chunks(lines), chunk2dataframe, hdrs=hdrs))
#   UNIQUE.ID          TYPES                        COMMON.NAME
# 1 CPD0-1108 D-Ribofuranose              &beta;-D-ribofuranose
# 2   URIDINE     Pyrimidine &beta;-D-ribofuranose or something
```

Since you want to iterate this over many functions, it makes sense to create a convenience function for this:

```
text2dataframe <- function(txt) {
  dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(text2chunks(txt), chunk2dataframe, hdrs=hdrs))
}
```

---

### Many Files

Untested, but should work:

```
files <- list.files(path="C:/Users/robbie/Desktop/Organism_Data/",
                    pattern="compounds.dat", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
alldata <- lapply(files, readLines)
allframes <- lapply(alldata, text2dataframe)
oneframe <- dplyr::bind_rows(allframes)
```

---

Notes:

- I'm using `stringi::stri_split` instead of `strsplit` simply for its convenience argument `n=`; doing the same in base R is not hard with a couple extra lines of code.
- I'm using `dplyr::bind_rows` because it deals very well with missing columns and differing order; base `rbind.data.frame` can be used with some extra effort/care.
- `data.frame`-izing things tends to nudge column names a little, just be aware.

---

Data:

```
# lines <- readLines("some_filename.dat")
fulltext <- 'Authors:
#    Pallavi Subhraveti
#    Quang Ong
# Please see the license agreement regarding the use of and distribution of this file.
# The format of this file is defined at http://bioinformatics.ai.sri.com
# Version: 21.5
# File Name: compounds.dat
# Date and time generated: October 24, 2017, 14:52:45
# Attributes:
#    UNIQUE-ID
#    TYPES
[Data Chunk 1]
UNIQUE-ID - CPD0-1108
TYPES - D-Ribofuranose
COMMON-NAME - &beta;-D-ribofuranose
DO-NOT-CARE - 42
[Data Chunk 2]
// something out of place here?
UNIQUE-ID - URIDINE
TYPES - Pyrimidine
COMMON-NAME - &beta;-D-ribofuranose or something
DO-NOT-CARE - 43
'
lines <- strsplit(fulltext, '[\r\n]+')[[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still looking for the desired output. Sorry for the confusion but my data doesn't have `[Data Chunk 1], [Data Chunk 2]` and so on. I edited that portion to get a clear understanding to the community member. The pattern in the data is before every `UNIQUE-ID`(one line before UNIQUE-ID) there are `//` these two characters. Can you help me how do I modify the code for the above pattern. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: I suspect it would be *trivial* to adapt to whatever your data actually looks like. Perhaps I can help if you provide accurate and representative sample data. (Otherwise, GIGO.)

Comment: I have updated my question with the link to data. Please help!