# Doing calculation for section of a data and averaging

Tags: r

I am trying to use R for my research and I have found it challenging to read a section of a file and do some calculation and do an average for the number of times the calculation is done. For example. I have a file like this:

frame

```
           1

 atoms in the system

       14657

 Box Dimensions
   5.870700    
   5.870700    
   5.870700    

 Methane molecules Trajectory
  14601  1      4.043000        1.539000        3.324000
  14602  1      3.979000        3.490000        1.266000
  14603  1      0.276000        1.889000        1.967000
  14604  1      3.710000        5.806000        1.362000
  14605  1      1.467000        1.433000        2.991000
  14606  1      2.675000        3.919000        1.486000
  14607  1      5.483000        0.201000        0.685000
  14608  1      5.371000        5.367000        3.819000

 frame
           2

 atoms in the system
       14657

 Box Dimensions
   5.870700    
   5.870700    
   5.870700    

 Methane molecules Trajectory
  14601  1      4.043000        1.539000        3.324000
  14602  1      3.979000        3.490000        1.266000
  14603  1      0.276000        1.889000        1.967000
  14604  1      3.710000        5.806000        1.362000
  14605  1      1.467000        1.433000        2.991000
  14606  1      2.675000        3.919000        1.486000
  14607  1      5.483000        0.201000        0.685000
  14608  1      5.371000        5.367000        3.819000

 frame
           3

 atoms in the system
       14657

 Box Dimensions
   5.870700    
   5.870700    
   5.870700    

 Methane molecules Trajectory
  14601  1      4.043000        1.539000        3.324000
  14602  1      3.979000        3.490000        1.266000
  14603  1      0.276000        1.889000        1.967000
  14604  1      3.710000        5.806000        1.362000
  14605  1      1.467000        1.433000        2.991000
  14606  1      2.675000        3.919000        1.486000
  14607  1      5.483000        0.201000        0.685000
  14608  1      5.371000        5.367000        3.819000
```

I need to skip the first 9 lines in each frame and do calculations with columns 3-5. I have to repeat the calculation for each of the frame and find an average. Could you please guide me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Are the lines `frame`, `atoms in the system`, etc file lines? And are there any blank lines? As I understand it, what you want is to load what comes after each `Methane molecules Trajectory` in a different table. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. What I need are the 8 lines after the methane molecule trajectory. I want to do some calculations like, counting the number of methane at a specific location in each frame and find average over the number of frames.

Comment: Perhaps something you can adapt: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51289972/3358272

Comment: It works! Thanks for your help Rui Barradas.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the following code will read in the tables in your example dataset from file.

First, choose the file interactively (or by any method you want).

```
fl <- file.choose()
```

Now, read in the full tables, each with 5 columns.

```
lns <- readLines(fl)
frm <- grep("frame", lns, ignore.case = TRUE)
frm <- c(frm[-1], length(lns))
mth <- grep("methane", lns, ignore.case = TRUE)

df_list <- lapply(seq_along(frm), function(i) {
  con <- textConnection(lns[ (mth[i] + 1):(frm[i] - 1) ])
  dat <- read.table(con)
  close.connection(con)
  dat
})
```

Finally, if you just want columns 3, 4 and 5, this will extract them and produce a list named `df_list3`.

```
df_list3 <- lapply(df_list, '[', 3:5)
```